# how to generate function signature with sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

The package structure and files are set up like this:

```
$ tree .
.
├── doc
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── _build
│   ├── _static
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── foo.rst
│   ├── index.rst
│   └── make.bat
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    └── spam.py


$ cat foo/__init__.py
r'''
The Foo module
==============

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated

   spam
'''


$ cat foo/spam.py
r'''
The Spam Module
===============
'''

def prepare(a):
    '''Prepare function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : int
    '''
    print(a)


$ cat doc/index.rst
Welcome to foo's documentation!
=====================================

API Reference
-------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   foo


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`


$ cat doc/foo.rst
.. automodule:: foo
```

After `make html` to generate sphinx documentation, function `prepare` is listed out but there are not signature of this function documented:

```
$ cat generated/foo.spam.rst
foo.spam
========
.. automodule:: foo.spam

   .. rubric:: Functions

   .. autosummary::

      prepare
```

My question is how to generate then, how can automatically generate the function signature in this case?

Comment: Are you expecting that `foo.spam.rst` will include the signature of `prepare` within the `autosummary` block?  Because it won't ... that will be generated by `autodoc` (and inserted into the resulting **output**)

Comment: The wording of the question is confusing. I don't understand "there are not signature of this function documented".  When you say "signature", do you actually mean "docstring"?

Answer (score 0):

```
.. automodule:: foo.spam
```

I think this is your problem (if you haven't solved it yet)

Wouldn't the correct way be

```
.. automodule:: spam
```

Comment: `generated/foo.spam.rst` is auto generated

Comment: yeah but automodule looks at the py not the rst

Answer (score 0):

### First issue I am seeing:

You might be confusing your `python` code with the Sphinx documentation, which is rendered from `.rst` files.

So, for example, if you want to document your `foo` module, it will not be generated from your code in init:

```
$ cat foo/__init__.py
r'''
The Foo module
==============

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated

   spam
'''
```

But rather you will need to open a file called `foo.rst` and inside it you can place your code for Sphinx to read:

```
$ cat doc/foo.rst
The Foo module
==============

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated

   spam
```

### Second thing to notice:

In the `index.rst` file, in the main Table Of Content (`toctree`), you can only link to **other .rst files**.

So to take for example the `foo.rst` file from the previous section, you could link to it here:

```
$ cat doc/index.rst
Welcome to foo's documentation!
=====================================

API Reference
-------------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   foo
```

### For more notes:

you can look in [this example documentation](https://dalyag.github.io/Sphinx185/index.html) I made. Each page contains the `.rst` source code so you can follow how it was made.

Good luck!